# Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined while reading json data to typescript

Tags: json, typescript

Getting below error message while trying to read a `description` attribute from below Sample Json.

> Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
>   while reading json data to typescript

```
import {Age} from "./sample" 
var a:Age;    
console.log(a.description);
```

**Sample.json** :

```
{
   "title":"Example Schema",
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{
      "firstName":{
         "type":"string"
      },
      "lastName":{
         "type":"string"
      },
      "age":{
         "description":"Age in years",
         "type":"integer",
         "minimum":0
      },
      "hairColor":{
         "enum":[
            "black",
            "brown",
            "blue"
         ],
         "type":"string"
      }
   },
   "additionalProperties":false,
   "required":[
      "firstName",
      "lastName"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Sample.json  : {
  "title": "Example Schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "age": {
      "description": "Age in years",
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0
    },
    "hairColor": {
      "enum": ["black", "brown", "blue"],
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}

Comment: sample.json                                                                                               export interface Age {
        description: string;
        type: string;
        minimum: number;
    }

Comment: use `JSON.parse` like here `let obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-json-undefined?embed=1&file=index.ts).

Since this is Typescript the trick is cast the `json` as the type needed. Since `sample.json` is more than the `Age` interface listed in the comments, we'll create a new interface, called PersonSchema.

```
interface PersonSchema {
  title: string;
  properties: {
    age: Age;
  };
}
```

Now we can import the `json` data. Note: `import {Age} from "./sample"` does not work because the sample file is `json` and cannot export a type.

```
import data from './sample.json';
```

Cast it as the type needed:

```
const person = data as PersonSchema;
```

Access the age:

```
const age = person.properties.age;
```